# Liquibase diffChangeLog does not report stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am new to Liquibase. I am using Liquibase version 4.0 and on Windows 10 Home edition

```
Starting Liquibase at 23:08:42 (version 4.0.0 #19 built at 2020-07-13 19:45+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.0.0
Liquibase Community 4.0.0 by Datical
```

I added one table and SP to `DATABASEONE`. I also generated diff between two databases and it worked fine.

```
liquibase diffChangeLog
```

liquibase.properties

```
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath=../mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre11.jar
url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DATABASETWO
username=sa
password=Password123
referenceUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DATABASEONE
referenceUsername=sa
referencePassword=Password123
changeLogFile=diff.xml
```

However, Liquibase does not report difference on stored procedures.

How can I get the newly added (or) missing stored procedure information in `diffChangeLog` ?

**EDIT**

I used Pro License Key (14-day trial) to generate the diff for Stored Procedures

I also generated `liquibase updateSQL > update.sql`.   Now I want to run 'update.sql' against another database.  How can I do that?

Comment: Could you try the `diff` command? Is it display differences in stored procedures?

Comment: Yes.  I already tried and SPs does not exists in the result file.  Meanwhile, I am using 14-day pro license key and now it produces SPs in the result file.  Not sure, whether SP changes will be captured only in PRO version

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/diffchangelog.html), the community version of liquibase will handle stored procedures with  `diffChangeLog` command. In my opinion, it is some kind of bug.

Comment: Edited the post with one more question.  Kindly respond if possible

Answer (score 0):

Running an update on the update.sql generatated the command liquibase updateSQL > update.sql will return extra stuff that is debug info.  Not just straight SQL.  You will want to:

- use generateChangelog to produce a changelog file (let's call it change.postgresql.xml)
- run liuqibase update using the above produced changelog file and url of destination db

Note, if they are different db platforms, like say from postgres->mysql, then you will have to review the generate changelog (in this case change.postgresql.xml) for non spec db objects of the target db (in this example mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't diff stored function / procedure according to [diff-changelog document](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/diff/diff-changelog.html)

> ### Additional Functionality with Liquibase Pro
>
> While Liquibase Open Source stores all changesets in a changelog, Liquibase Pro creates a directory called Objects and places the directory at the same level as your changelog. The Objects directory contains a subdirectory for each of the following stored logic types:
>
> - checkconstraint
> - package
> - packagebody
> - procedure
> - **function**
> - **trigger**
> - synonyms